# Replacing a ceiling light with a fan. light used house white, red, ground. house black was capped

Tags: wiring

The fan is now installed and working correctly.  Thank you to everyone for your help.

I am replacing a wall switch controlled ceiling light with a fan.  (note:  the fixture is marked as being acceptable for a fan).  While removing the light I noticed the wiring was:

- house white to light white
- house RED to light black
- box ground to light ground (both bare copper)
- house black capped off, not connected to anything
  The light was working with this wiring configuration.

My question: when I install the fan should I follow what the light did or follow the fan instructions which would be:

- house white to fan white
- house black to fan black   (old light did not use house black)
- house red to ?
- box copper to fan grounds

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the ceiling box and switch box?  Normally we'll say to wire it up just like the old one but the house green to light black is wrong. You'll need to figure out the wiring because something's amiss.

Comment: Your location will help also.  In most of the world this would be bad, and hoping you have some colour blindness.

Comment: I am in Arizona. House built in 2000 or so.  Bought  the house about a year ago and the ceiling box was painted over as the house was painted by the previous owners just prior to selling it.      I am color blind but the wires were painted over and I scrapped off the paint and wife confirmed the colors.

Comment: The only house green should be ground.  It is only allowed for ground wires along with bare and green with yellow line.  Do you have cable or conduit for your wires?  Conduit would give a reason for there being a green wire there, not a good reason but a reason.

Comment: Switch box: I see red, black and bare ground on the switch - perfectly normal. Bundle of white neutrals - perfectly normal. Ceiling box - not so clear - but looks like black (capped), red (unknown), white (unknown), bare (unknown). **kafAZ - Please describe where you see "green" and also whether or not you see "red" for the wire sticking out to the left in the ceiling and twisted with the black wire on the switch.**

Comment: So I am a colorblind idiot.   in the ceiling:  house black unused,  house RED to light black, house white to light white, box copper to light copper.           based on the fan instructions I was looking for house black/white/green.

Comment: Not an idiot. An idiot is someone who sees something strange, doesn't question it, copies it elsewhere and burns the house down. Which really does happen

Comment: You saw something odd, you ask a question, this makes you a smart/wise person.

Answer (score 0):

Totally revised answer. I *suspect* color-blindness of some variety. A bit hard to tell for sure due to typical paint-on-the-wires, but I see:

- Switch - black, red, bare ground
- Light - black (capped), red, white, ground

which points to "green is the new red", or something like that. *And now I see the value of green/yellow for ground. Which is legitimate in the US but far more common overseas.*

If indeed that's the case then everything is OK and possibly even *better* than just "OK". You can have black/white/red as a switch loop or as a "2 wires can be switched" setup. It can't be a switch loop because then black would not be capped. Which *should* mean that the red and black wires on the switch are from two *different* cables. If that's the case then the black wire from the cable with the red wire can be used as an alternate switched wire. That can be used to have separately switched light and fan. The alternative is a remote control and the wall switch turns *everything* on/off but doesn't control the light and fan separately. If they can be separately switched then that also allows for a dimmer on the light and a speed control for the fan (they are conceptually the same but technically quite different).

Comment: pictures of the two boxes are here:  https://imgur.com/a/URlfajj

Comment: the fan has a remote and has lights but only one set of wires (black/white/green (definitely green - per the manual not me looking at it)).      so I think I should wire like the light was wired,  house RED to fan black, and leave the switch to on, and just use the remote.

Comment: The cable from the switch box to the ceiling box has three insulated conductors--black, red, white. A light only would need only one hot (red or black) and the neutral (white).  Therefore one hot was capped off. A fan with a light kit can share the one neutral, but would need separate hots to be controlled separately from two wall switches. The wiring in the fan housing is usually a black wire for the fan hot and a blue for the light kit hot.  The hots from the switches are black from one switch and red from the other switch. OK to use B to B or R to B for the fan and the other hot to blue